# Arbitrary expression error in same context: Static method requires null instance

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
>    Parameter name: method

But it is raised in one place, and in another place, in the same scenario it doesn't. For instance in this usage, all works fine:

```
    public async Task<ValueServiceResult<PagedEnumerable<GenreDto>>> List(int page, int pageSize, int? parentCategory = null)
    {

        return await TryCatchAsync(async () =>
        {
            var whereQuery = parentCategory.HasValue
                ? GetExpression<Genre>(g => g.ParentCategoryId == parentCategory.Value)
                : null;
            var items = await Repository.GeneralQueryPaged(page, pageSize, whereQuery,
                c => c.Name);
            var mappedResult = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<GenreDto>>(items);
            return new ValueServiceResult<PagedEnumerable<GenreDto>>(new PagedEnumerable<GenreDto>(mappedResult, items.Total, pageSize));
        });
    }
```

And in this another usage, it raise the exception:

```
    public async Task<ValueServiceResult<PagedEnumerable<ArtistDto>>> List(int page, int pageSize, string filter)
    {
        return await TryCatchAsync(async () =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
                filter = filter.Trim().ToLower();
            var whereQuery = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)
                ? GetExpression<Artist>(a => true) /*a.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter)*/
                : null;

            var items = await Repository.GeneralQueryPaged(page, pageSize, whereQuery, c => c.Name);
            var mappedResult = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ArtistDto>>(items);
            return new ValueServiceResult<PagedEnumerable<ArtistDto>>(new PagedEnumerable<ArtistDto>(mappedResult, items.Total, pageSize));
        });
    }
```

The exception is raised in `GetExpression` call. This is a static method in a parent class. This is how it is implemented:

```
    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetExpression<TEntity> (Func<TEntity, bool> funct)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Call(funct.Method));
    }
```

I just can't understand, how it is possible that this error is raised in one usage, but not in another usage. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Expression.Call`, that's only used for calling actual methods.

Use `Expression.Invoke` to invoke delegates.

There's many reasons why the `Call` might work in some places but not others - most likely, the kind that works has a closure, while the one that doesn't... doesn't. I'd still expect everything to break in runtime, though, since you're never passing the proper arguments to the `Expression.Call` - you need to pass the lambda parameters (and in the closure case, the closure instance).

Note that if you're using this helper method for interfacing with something like Entity Framework, it most likely will not work anyway - in C#, methods aren't automatically quoted, so all that EF sees is the method call - it doesn't see inside the method. If you're only using this to be called later (using e.g. `Compile().Invoke()`), though, you're fine.

A code sample:

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Wrap<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> func)
{
    var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
    return 
        Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>
        (
            Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(func), entity), 
            entity
        );
}
```

Comment: In that case, how can I use the `Invoke` instead of `Call`, can you show some code sample in your answer? Thanks for answering!

Comment: I the case it works, EF works fine, due that are methods call that EF can translate to SQL, the error is raised in the Expression creation, no in the EF execution.

Comment: @RaúlOtaño It's going to raise another in the EF execution as well - EF can't look *inside* the methods to check if it can translate them to SQL. It simply doesn't work that way. However, I don't see why you'd need such an operation anyway, since you're using anonymous methods - why not just use an `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` directly?

Comment: @RaúlOtaño There are two possibilities. The first is that EF throws an error when executing the query. The second is that EF never gets passed the filter, and all your filtering is done client-side. There is no way that EF translates delegate invocations to SQL.

Comment: Using `Expression.Invoke` raises an EF exception: `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`. The only propose of that method, is getting an `Expression` from the lambda, and, in that way, pass the expression to the linq query.

Comment: @RaúlOtaño Yup. `Expression.Call` will say something like "the method call doesn't correspond to a known method". Again, *why* are you using `Func<...>` at all, instead of only using `Expression<Func<...>>`?

Comment: @Luann Yes, you are absolutely right. using directly `Expression<Func<...>>` works. I may use directly like this: `Expression<Func<Artist, bool>> whereQuery = null;` and set the variable if needed.